# Display a Toast message to add text instead of the app crashing

Tags: java, android, windows

Hey guys I have a question when I add some text in the box it works but when I don't add anything inside, the project crashes. Is there a way to be able to add an **if statement** to the project to ask the user (via  Toast) to add something instead of crashing the app? Thanks

this is the code I have so far

```
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public void convert(View view) {

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.enterNumber);

        double enteredNumber = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString());
        double converted = (Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString()) * 100)/100*106.111;

        final String usFormat = String.format("%.2f", enteredNumber);
        final String japanFormat = String.format("%.2f",converted);




        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "$" +usFormat + " USD is = " +
              "¥" + japanFormat +  " Yen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Button pressed", "Pressed");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

this is the xml code I have to set up

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="Enter an amount to convert"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="convert"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.254" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="287dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/money" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: show error log please

Comment: Displaying a toast instead of addressing the underlying issue is... inelegant (and honestly, ineffective). Why don't you look through your logcat and find the error message and edit your post to include it? Imagine you wake up one morning with a hole through your head. Do you think putting on a hat is the right way to deal with that kind of problem?

Comment: @MarsAtomic depending on where the hole is, _thinking_ might be quite hard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, all you need is validate the user input before converting it into an `Double` number.

Then, you may want to surround your code with `try` `catch` block to prevent when the input string is not a number.

Try this:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.enterNumber);
    
String value = textView.getText().toString();
if (value.equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "Field must not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
try {
    double enteredNumber = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString());
    double converted = (Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString()) * 100) / 100 * 106.111;
    final String usFormat = String.format("%.2f", enteredNumber);
    final String japanFormat = String.format("%.2f", converted);


    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "$" + usFormat + " USD is = " +
                "¥" + japanFormat + " Yen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("Button pressed", "Pressed");
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "Value is not a number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: can you give me a recap of how you got this. I spent over an hour and still could not figure it out

Comment: You're welcome, mate :) It's just a little experience when i facing issues related to input field with number value.

Comment: how long you been doing android dev.?

Comment: just around a year actually.

Comment: impressive mate

Comment: Thank you :) if my answer solved your problem, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer), so people know the problem has been solved.